# PHP if statment Checking to see if equal the same number

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, preg-match

I am trying to do a check to find out if variables match and if they do match show this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php

list($ccvRecords, $ccvMetaData) = getRecords(array(
'tableName'   => 'videos',
'loadUploads' => true,
'where' => "num NOT LIKE '%{$CurrentCCVideo}%'",
'allowSearch' => false,
```

));

```
list($ccvSelRecords, $ccvSelMetaData) = getRecords(array(
'tableName'   => 'videos',
'loadUploads' => true,
'allowSearch' => false,
```

));

?>

```
<?php foreach($ccvSelRecords as $record) : ?>
<?php if ($CurrentCCVideo === $record['num']) : ?>
<label class="margin-top-10"><?php echo($record['title']) ?> is selected</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control input-lg" name="meta_keywords" onClick="dosomething" value="0">
<?php else : ?>
<label class="margin-top-10"><?php echo($record['title']) ?></label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control input-lg" name="meta_keywords" onClick="dosomething" value="0">
<?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: What is your actual question? Please update your post to include what is wrong, not working, what you get vs. what you want to get. Update the post (don't answer in a comment) and don't put stuff like **Edit** or **Update** in your revised question when you do. This site has edit history, those who need to see differences can get the information from there.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if (($CurrentCCVideo = $record['num'])==TRUE)
```

to

```
if (($CurrentCCVideo == $record['num']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<?php if (($CurrentCCVideo = $record['num'])==TRUE) : ?>
```

with

```
<?php if ($CurrentCCVideo == $record['num']) : ?>
```

Try this now ..

Comment: nope this did not work, the above values in each variables should read if 7=7 > show this

Comment: $CurrentCCVideo and $record['num'] both equal the same number

Comment: you can also use === ternary equal operator but I think first you need to do
echo $record['num'];
echo $CurrentCCVideo; 
and check both having some values or not??

Comment: what I'm trying to do is check if a current value is the same as the current record num. So for example if $record['num'] and $CurrentCCVideo are a value of 7 (7 = 7) then it would show that record. others would be everythig but that record. I was hoping to accomplish this with an if statement.

Comment: yes I understand your requirement and this must be accomplished with if condition like if ($CurrentCCVideo == $record['num']).
But I want you to print the both before the if condition to make sure that they have any values or not like echo $record['num']; echo $CurrentCCVideo;

Comment: I echoed both outside of the condition and they both output 7, when i manually type 7 instead of $CurrentCCVideo it works as I want it to, So i am thinking it's a syntax issue???

Comment: Its possible may be space is come into one of them therefore its not comparing even both have 7 value as you said. So try two different functions for. May be one of the function will work. if (trim($CurrentCCVideo) == trim($record['num'])) if not work than try if (intval($CurrentCCVideo) == intval($record['num'])) Let me know if this is work for you .. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
if(is_numeric($element))
{
 //your code 
}

<?php foreach($ccvRecords as $record) : ?>
<?php if ($CurrentCCVideo ==== $record['num']) : ?>
<label class="margin-top-10"><?php echo($record['title']) ?> is selected</label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control input-lg" name="meta_keywords" onClick="dosomething" value="0">
<?php else : ?>
<label class="margin-top-10"><?php echo($record['title']) ?></label>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control input-lg" name="meta_keywords" onClick="dosomething" value="0">
<?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: if($CurrentCCVideo($record['num']))

Comment: ^ is that how i would apply the variables

Comment: I am not sure how I am to apply this to my code? Sorry I am learning php as I go

Comment: where is the part in this code that checks if $CurrentCCVideo and $record['num'] are the same value? this is how it would read if 7 = 7 { show value } else   anything with a value that isn't the $CurrentCCVideo value

Comment: check it now if you want to compare you just need to use === operator for compare . it will match the equal value as well as type .

Comment: when trying that it produced results for the <? else ?> but not the first half, the half that match records

Comment: have you tried to echo the $CurrentCCVideo  and $record['num']???? i think you are not getting one value from these two variable.

Comment: yes I did this earlier to verify they were both outputting the same number. Both echoed a value of 7.